# Input and Output text files

Tags: c++, loops, visual-c++, fstream, nested-loops

I'm doing a simple assignment and I'm having trouble outputting the intended output.  Can someone help me gain direction in figuring out where the issue is?  We're not allowed to use istringstream.

```
    else
    {
       upData >> houseIdent;

       while(upData)
       {

         do{
                upData >> vehType >> plate >> year >> vehPrice;

                calculate = calcReg(vehType, plate, year,
                                vehPrice);

                outDataOne << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
                outDataOne << ' ' << vehType << ' ' << plate << ' ' << calculate
                           << endl;


                ch = upData.peek();

          }while (upData && (ch != '\n'));  

          upData >> houseIdent;

    }
```

upData is the ifstream .txt and outDataOne is the ofstream .txt. The input is similar to this

11111 M DKC294 2007 23001 A VID392 2010 10390
22222 A DKS382 2011 20390
33333 A DKF329 2001 30920 M AJD302 2004 15509

The output I keep getting though is the first two output lines are correct but then the third line doesn't go back and read the 2nd line ID number, but keeps 11111 as the ID number while putting the vehType as 2 and the plate as 0390.  I'm so confused with this as I am fairly new to C++.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/HzJoPi)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I took your code and modified it slightly so I could run it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  #define upData std::cin
  #define outDataOne std::cout

  string houseIdent;
  char vehType;
  string plate;
  int year;
  int vehPrice;
  int ch;
  upData >> houseIdent;
  while (upData) {
    do {
      upData >> vehType >> plate >> year >> vehPrice;

      auto calculate = 237237; // calcReg(vehType, plate, year, vehPrice);

      outDataOne << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2);
      outDataOne << ' ' << vehType << ' ' << plate << ' ' << calculate << endl;

      ch = upData.peek();

    } while (upData && (ch != '\n'));

    upData >> houseIdent;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And fed it your input:

11111 M DKC294 2007 23001 A VID392 2010 10390
22222 A DKS382 2011 20390
33333 A DKF329 2001 30920 M AJD302 2004 15509

And it spit this out:

M DKC294 237237
 A VID392 237237
 A DKS382 237237
 A DKF329 237237
 M AJD302 237237

Which appears to be doing the right thing.  This appears to leave more questions than answers, but:

1) Note that when you call peek(), it returns an int, not a char, since the result might be an EOF.  You don't show the declarations of any of your variables, but that might be a small issue.

2) You don't check for running out of input right after your "update >> vehType ..." line.  You really need to do that, since the stream won't report an EOF until you ask it for data it can't supply.  As the code stands, it looks like it might use stale data on the last time through the loop.

3) You say the vehType is reported as 2 while the plate is 0390; this likely means it interpreted "20390" as a combination of one character of vehType and the rest as a string.  I don't see how this could happen (and it didn't when I tried it), but my guess is that you have a hidden garbage character in your input that is throwing things off.  (Perhaps a unicode non-breaking space or somesuch?)  It would greatly help to add a debugging line where you print out all the vehType / plate / year / vehPrice values that it reads in, right when they're being read in, to see where the code is going wrong.

Comment: I'm looking at it and it seems to not be reading the last upData >> houseIdent;.  It seems that input is being skipped and I'm wondering why it's being skipped.